# Issue with iPhone for playing music in the car

Tags: iphone, audio, usb, bluetooth, lightning

For the past 2 days, I haven't been able to play music from my iPhone in my car with bluetooth, nor with a USB connection.

If I connect the iPhone with bluetooth, the **phone-calls work well**.
I have always listened to music from my iPhone in my car (**Bluetooth or USB**) with Spotify App, but it doesn't work without explication.

It seems that the multimedia options were blocked.

I have tested in other car and the problem is the same. 
**I have tested with a iPod via USB and it works well.**
I have tested with a bluetooth speaker connected to my iphone and it works well.
I have restarted my iPhone and restarted the bluetooth connection. unlinking bluetooth and reconnecting car and iPhone.

**So I think that the issue is with iPhone - some option or something blocked.**

I dont use CarPlay.

Can you help me?
Someone who has happened it?

Thank you!